# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xml.resolver.readers.CatalogReader

Tags: java, classpath

I'm working on a java application which validate my input xml messages. I've used resolver classes (org.apache.xml.resolver.*) and I have exported my code as a jar file and trying to execute on aix machine.! Unfortunately I'm getting an exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xml.resolver.readers`.CatalogReader. I have included **resolver.jar** in a path and included that in classpath, not worked. Then **tried keeping that jar file under java/lib folder**, still getting the same error.!!

Comment: This is caused when there is a class file that your code depends on and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Look for differences in your build time and runtime classpaths.

Comment: Thank you Rishikesh, 
I have actually build this on eclipse and exported as jar. Then moved this jar to AIX. Should I worry about the build time classpath..?

Comment: jar/zip files have to be explicitly added to the classpath, it's not enough only add the containing directory (it is not AIX-specific)

    -cp somewhere/somethin.jar:elsewhere/else.jar